# HTML insert "tab"

Tags: html, css

I would like the text (see PIC2) that every text begins in the same place, so to speak, provided with a tab. In Word that's just a tab. But how does that work in HTML or CSS? Can someone help me and tell me how I can make PIC1 from PIC2?

PIC1:

[image: pic 1]

PIC2:

[image: pic 2]

Code:

```
<p><strong>Öffnungzeiten:</strong>
        <p>Montag Geschlossen<br/>
        Dienstag 09:00 - 18:00<br/>
        Mittwoch Geschlossen<br/>
        Donnerstag 09:00 - 18:00<br/>
        Freitag 09:00 - 18:00<br/>
        Samstag 09:00 - 13:00<br/>
        Sonntag Geschlossen</p>
```

Comment: Logically you have a list consisting of two columns, so your html and css should reflect that organization.  Conceptualizing that as a table also makes sense. Making random divs to float things around makes less logical sense and will be harder to keep your code organized for future changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.poperty-container{
clear:both;
}
.key-div
{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}
.value-div
{
width:50%;
float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class='poperty-container'>
  <div class='key-div'>
    Montag 
  </div>
  <div class='value-div'>
    Geschlossen
  </div>
</div>


<div class='poperty-container'>
  <div class='key-div'>
    Dienstag 
  </div>
  <div class='value-div'>
    09:00 - 18:00
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a line break, separate them into two sections with a margin in between.

```html
<div style="display: flex">
    <div>
      <p>Montag</p>
      <p>Dienstag</p>
      <p>Mittwoch</p>
      <p>Donnerstag</p>
      <p>Freitag</p>
      <p>Samstag</p>
      <p>Sonntag</p>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 2rem">
      <p>Geschlossen</p>
      <p>09:00 - 18:00</p>
      <p>Geschlossen</p>
      <p>09:00 - 18:00</p>
      <p>09:00 - 18:00</p>
      <p>09:00 - 13:00</p>
      <p>Geschlossen</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use columns. This site should help:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

```html
<style>
  .columns {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
    column-gap: 8px;
    column-fill: auto;
  }
  
  #column1 {
    column-span: none;
  }
  
  li {
    list-style-type: none
  }
</style>
<div class="columns">
  <div id="column1">
    <ul>
      <li>Montag </li>
      <li>Dienstag</li>
      <li>Mittwoch</li>
      <li>Donnerstag</li>
      <li>Freitag</li>
      <li>Samstag</li>
      <li>Sonntag</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="column2">
    <ul><br/>
      <li>Geschlossen</li>
      <li>09:00 - 18:00</li>
      <li>Geschlossen</li>
      <li>09:00 - 18:00</li>
      <li>09:00 - 18:00</li>
      <li>09:00 - 13:00</li>
      <li>Geschlossen</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you are only providing a link you should do that with a comment. To post an answer you should explain the relevant details from the link and provide a working example here.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into ASCII codes. The one for tab is `&#009;`

Find the whole list at [ascii-code.com](http://www.ascii-code.com)

Comment: HTML uses [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html), not ASCII. Another example: &#x1F4A1; 

Answer (score 0):

You can put the ASCII character code in for tabs in HTML (`&#` followed by `9;`). However note that HTML paragraphs don't show them as tabs. You can instead use `pre` preformatted blocks if you really want to do it the tab way:

```html
<p><strong>Öffnungzeiten:</strong>
<pre>
    Montag&#9;Geschlossen<br />
    Dienstag&#9;9:00 - 18:00<br />
    Mittwoch&#9;Geschlossen<br />
    Donnerstag&#9;09:00 - 18:00<br />
    Freitag&#9;09:00 - 18:00<br />
    Samstag&#9;09:00 - 13:00<br />
    Sonntag&#9;Geschlossen
</pre>
```

Taking a step back however, I'd advise using a table (basic) or divs (marginally more advanced). 
Simple table, for example:

```html
<p><strong>Öffnungzeiten:</strong>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Montag</td><td>Geschlossen</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Dienstag</td><td>9:00 - 18:00</td>
    </tr>
    .
    .
    .
</table>
```

Or read about divs here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp.

Answer (score 0):

## Key value List html

Adding each section of text to its own div makes teh content grow shrink to the text size.
I also added a margin so its always spaced apart.

```css
.inline-div {
  display: inline-block;
}

.extra-margin {
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="inline-div">
    <p>
      <label>long text here</label><br>
      <label>text</label><br>
      <label>text</label><br>
      <label>text</label>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="inline-div extra-margin">
    <p>
      test
      <br> test
      <br> test
      <br> test
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you need with a combination of pre, the tab character (&#9) and setting the tab-size to whatever you want in CSS:

```css
pre {tab-size: 8;}
```

```html
<pre>
  Montag&#9 Geschlossen<br/>
  Dienstag&#9 09:00 - 18:00<br/>
  Mittwoch&#9 Geschlossen<br/>
  Donnerstag&#9 09:00 - 18:00<br/>
  Freitag&#9 09:00 - 18:00<br/>
  Samstag&#9 09:00 - 13:00<br/>
  Sonntag&#9 Geschlossen
</pre>
```

(tab-size isn't fully supported yet but the browsers that are lagging with this should render this ok using their default tab-size)